# Is it possible to perform an uninstallation of several installed applications with a batch-file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to uninstall 12 applications. I would like to do it through a batch-file. I want to automate the uninstallation process.

What I want to do:

1. Check if application is installed 
   (if yes go to step 2; if no go to step 3)
2. Check if application is running right now
   (if yes end process; if no go to step 3)
3. Start uninstalling 
   (check every 3 sec if uninstall is finished)
   step 3 is the most confusing one for me
   I googled and found that you can check if the application.exe is running and check so if the uninstalling process is still running

4.if uninstalling is finsihed 
-->start uninstalling next application

however is this possible with a batch file?
I am pretty new to programing. pls show mercy

greetings

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What did you try?  Did you try to search the SO for your answer?  I have tried a simple search and found at least two hits:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861432/batch-file-to-uninstall-a-program and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995241/is-there-uninstall-a-program-batch-for-windows

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Formulated as an answer because it's too large for a comment)

What you ask, might be possible, but it's not that simple: you can launch following query to get installed products:

```
wmic product list
```

This might give you the list of installed products, but some products (like Notepad.exe) are not in that list, so be careful there.
Also the link between installed product and application name (which you can find, using `tasklist`) is not that straightforward.

I have the impression that you have a fix list of 12 applications you'd like to check, and you're looking for a general way to uninstall all of them. I'm afraid that, if not all those products are similar, that you might need a separate way of getting the job done for some of them.

Comment: `WMIC Product` uses the  `Win32_Product` class which only represents installations which used Windows Installer, _(e.g. `.msi` files)_.

Comment: @Dominique thank you for your quick reply. These 12 applications are similiar and also listed under the "product list". When I start an uninstallation, how do I know is it finished yet or not? I uninstalled one of those application and the name was just application1.exe running as a process. So could i take that to check the "uninstallation status"?

Comment: @DeheiBide, when you run `WMIC Product Where "Name='Some Application 2018'" Call Uninstall`, from a Command Prompt window,  does the uninstall not complete before returning focus back to the prompt? _(i.e. Does it start the uninstallation routine, then begin the next line before the first has completed)_?

Comment: Okay. Apperantly I don't need to check if the uninstallation is running because it says "executing" and does not go to the next command until it is fisnished. That makes it easy :). Thank you Dominique and Compo

Answer (score 0):

if a GUI is a suitable option to you and you don't need it to be command-line, then BCUninstaller will do bulk uninstall and cleanup for your windows programs: https://sourceforge.net/projects/bulk-crap-uninstaller/