# Batch command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file that contains the names of some programs like Ask Toolbar, and mywebsearch Toolbar and different programs like that.  My question is how would I search the registry to find and call the uninstall string for each program through batch?  All ideas are welcome I have come to a stand still

Answer (score 0):

I'd start my grep here, find your app in the list to narrow down your search.

```
REG EXPORT HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall C:\HKLM_Uninstall_List.reg
```

I find the uninstall string for my Ram Disk here.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ImDisk]
"DisplayName"="ImDisk Virtual Disk Driver"
"UninstallString"="rundll32.exe setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection DefaultUninstall 132
```

Once we know the exact path, reg query it.

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ImDisk /v UninstallString
```

Comment: If the text file has the exact names as listed in the reg export, we can fully automate with simple loop.

Comment: Or they might be in HKCU key.  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Answer (score 0):

Every program that properly installs itself according to Microsoft's guidelines makes a registry entry in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. Usually, the key for the program will be its GUID, or else the name of the program. Within that key will be an entry called `UninstallString`. This contains the command to execute to uninstall the program.

If you already know what you will be uninstalling, it should be easy enough to just put that in your batch file. It gets tricky when you try to automate that process though. You can use the reg command to get data from the registry, but it returns a lot of text around the actual value of a given key, making it hard to use. You may want to experiment with using VBscript or PowerShell, as they have better options for getting data from the registry into a variable.

**You can try scripts from here.....**

[Check the answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995241/is-there-uninstall-a-program-batch-for-windows?rq=1)

[Check answer here too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864144/how-to-create-a-script-via-batch-file-that-will-uninstall-a-program-if-it-was-in)